# How to declare a static variable with base url in Yii

Tags: yii

I am using a variable

```
$path = Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images1/';
```

in many functions of a controller. How can i declare it as global?

Comment: Check this article: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/126/setting-and-getting-systemwide-static-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

In your main.php config you may use `params`.

```
...
// application-level parameters that can be accessed
// using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
'params'            => require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
```

In params.php, for example.

```
return [
    ...
    'imagesPath' => __DIR__ . '/../../images1/',
];
```

PHP 5.3+ required to use `__DIR__` constant.

With PHP 5.2 you may use `dirname(__FILE__)` expression.